# Compras no app através da operadora

Tags: java, android

Hoje em dia em meu aplicativo utilizo o sistema in-app-billing, porém gostaria de saber se há possibilidade de realizar vendas e efetuar cobranças pelo crédito da operadora do dispositivo do usuário.

Será possível? Em uma época já consegui efetuar compras pela operada.

Comment: Você teve algum progresso no assunto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não. Atualmente não é possivel usar compras pela operadora e partilhar do sistema in-app-billing disponivel pela google.

O que podes usar é um sistema de SMS billing onde as transações monetárias são efetuadas por SMS.

Alguns sítios pode onde pode começar:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_payment

http://www.junglepay.com/

https://secure.zaypay.com/overview